# Dropdown disappears on clicking scrollbar- typeahead bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using the Typeahead Bootstrap which returns a longer list of results. I've set a height to the dropdown menu and made the overflow-y: auto so that the user can scroll through the results. Now on clicking on the scrollbar the menu disappears. 
js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXebv/3/

I saw few posts with similar issues and i got the hint to add `event.preventDefault()` to the typehead function, but im not sure how can i add the `preventDefault()` in this scenario:

```
$('input').typeahead({
  source: items,
   items: 9999
});
```

any ideass? thanks

Comment: Js fiddle what you have shared is worked perfectly for me.